# Tokenizing chemical compounds

Tags: java, lucene, tokenize

i'm new to Lucene, so, i'm asking advice.

My project should tokenize different chemical (mostly organical) compounds, alongside other words. 
In the past I've used *StopAnalyzer* with *stop-words dictionary*, but now i can't do this as it tokenizes non-letter symbols. 
I cant find description of all TokenFilter types and have not idea how i can do this.
I am thinking of implementing a new Tokenize class of lucene and add to that class [OSCAR4 library](https://bitbucket.org/wwmm/oscar4/wiki/Home), however I don't understand how I could use common tokenizer in my class.

Please advise.

Example of text:

> The present invention relates to new crystalline forms of
>   4,4'-[4-fluoro-7-({4-[4-(3-fluoro-2-methylphenyl)butoxy]phenyl}ethynyl)-2-methyl-1H-indole-1,3-diyl]dibutanoic
>   acid (hereinafter sometimes abbreviated to compound I),
>   4,4'-[2-methyl-7-({4-[4-(pentafluorophenyl)butoxy]phenyl}ethynyl)-1H-indole-1,3-diyl]dibutanoic
>   acid (hereinafter sometimes abbreviated to compound II), and
>   4,4'-[4-fluoro-2-methyl-7-({4-[4-(2,3,4,6-tetrafluorophenyl)butoxy]phenyl}ethynyl)-1H-indole-1,3-diyl]dibutanoic
>   acid (hereinafter sometimes abbreviated to compound III).